# AngularJS not overriding built-in validator

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm trying to override the e-mail validator from AngularJS, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

This is the code that I have for the JavaScript file:

```
var app = angular.module("home", []);


app.directive("overwriteEmail", function() {
var UEMAIL_REGEX = /^[a-z0-9]+@university\.edu$/i;
 return {
   require: "ngModel",
   restrict: "",
   link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
   if (ctrl && ctrl.$validators.email) {
   ctrl.$validators.email = function(modelValue) {
     return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || UEMAIL_REGEX.test(modelValue);
   };

 }

}
 };


});
```

For the HTML file I have this:

```
<label>University Email Address:</label>
<input type="email" overwrite-email name="uemail" data-ng-model="email" placeholder="University e-mail required" required>
<span class="warning" data-ng-show="regis.uemail.$error.email">Invalid email!</span>
```

My code validates up to the @ sign, then it doesn't seem to care what comes after the @ symbol. What approach can I take to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use priority:2 which is greater than ng-model having priority:1 :-) it may override the email property.

```
app.directive("overwriteEmail", function() {
var UEMAIL_REGEX = /^[a-z0-9]+@university\.edu$/i;
 return {
   require: "ngModel",
   restrict: "",
   priority:2,
   link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
   if (ctrl && ctrl.$validators.email) {
   ctrl.$validators.email = function(modelValue) {
     return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || UEMAIL_REGEX.test(modelValue);
   };

 }

}
 };
```

Ps:-Provided you have 1.3.x

Comment: I just realized that I was using version 1.2.x instead of 1.3.x. The above code works without priority in version 1.3.x.